# How can I force GPG to accept input from STDIN instead of trying to open a file?

Tags: php, bash, lamp, gnupg, passphrase

I am trying to incorporate GPG's clear-signing of text in a string in a PHP script. I can cause GPG to encrypt text in a string like this:

```
$encrypted = shell_exec("echo '$text' | gpg -e -a -r foo@bar.com --trust-model always");
```

and that works perfectly, with the encrypted text being sent to the `$encrypted` variable. This proves GNUPGHOME and GNUPG are set up correctly.

However, when I try to produce a clear-signed message in the same way with this:

```
$text = "googar";

$signature = exec("echo $passphrase | gpg -v --clearsign --no-tty --passphrase-fd 0 '$text' 2>&1 1> /dev/null", $output);
```

I get this error:

```
... string(51) "gpg: can't open `googar': No such file or directory"
[3]=>
string(46) "gpg: googar: clearsign failed: file open error"
}
```

This error is returned with or without the single quotes around the `$text` variable.

How can I force GPG or `shell_exec` to treat `$text` as a pipe instead of it looking for a file?

I need to echo the passphrase in this way. I know, it's 'horribly insecure' because GPG has no way to pass in a passphrase as a variable on the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and create a separate file descriptor for your password:

```php
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("pipe", "w"),
    3 => array("pipe", "r"),
);

$pipes = false;
$process = proc_open("gpg -v --clearsign --no-tty --passphrase-fd 3", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if(is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[3], $passphrase);
    fclose($pipes[3]);

    fwrite($pipes[0], $text);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    $retval = proc_close($process);

    echo "retval = $retval\n";
    echo "output= $output\n";
    echo "err= $stderr\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, problem solved. I dropped in your code, and it just works. I will study its parts to learn something new. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
echo $passphrase | gpg -v -o- --clearsign --passphrase-fd 0 <(printf "$text")
```

This will make GPG think it is reading data from a file, but the file will be a temporary named pipe whose input will be `printf "$text"`.

`-o-` causes GPG to write the message and its signature to standard out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It now returns no error, but also does not display the GPG signed output.

Comment: True, no output, because stdout and stderr are piped to /dev/null.  Try without `2>&1 1> /dev/null`at the end, and if the result is ok, I will update the answer (I am too lazy to build the test case myself).